# Ubuntu 14.04 - enable numlock on login

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, numlock

Numlock is not activated in lightdm:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1271953

Workaround for ubuntu 13.10 :

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx

gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Add `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on` line to the end of file.

In ubuntu 14.04 the file `50-unity-greeter.conf` is missing.

Any ideas for a solution ?